# Can we program a burner software like Nero in JAVA only,... HOW?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading and Writing to a DVD/CD - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556291/reading-and-writing-to-a-dvd-cd-java)

Is possible to build/code a burner software like Nero in JAVA Only ? ... How do that ?

That's will be great if it's possible !!

Thank you

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556291/reading-and-writing-to-a-dvd-cd-java

Comment: sounds like a dupplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556291/reading-and-writing-to-a-dvd-cd-java

Comment: Is there any reason you would use one of the many tools written to do this already?

Comment: @Mouchakis5550 Who do you want to explain more about what?

Comment: Excuse me Mr. Peter, i don't understand : "Is there any reason you would use one of the many tools written to do this already?", is that sentence that i talk about

Answer (score 3):

No. Java does not have direct access to the hardware from pure Java code. You'd have to use native code loaded via JNI calls.

Comment: do mean that I need to use only C or C++ with JAVA 'using JNI'

Comment: Yes. You need to load C/C++ code designed to interact with the hardware into the JVM using JNI.