# How can I write a program to burn CD/DVD by Java?

Tags: java, cross-platform, dvd-burning, cd-burning

I've searched in Internet about burning CD/DVD that can work either in Linux and Windows. but unfortunately, I couldn't find a good solution.

Somebody suggested me, use commands line that related to Operating system. but I think it'd better write a good code that be able to use everywhere.

All my needs are described below:

1. get list of accessible driver name
2. get list of writer speed that any driver can do.
3. burn CD/DVD

So, If you can solve this problem, help me.
Thank you

Comment: People have already achieved this, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556291/reading-and-writing-to-a-dvd-cd-java

Comment: Yes, I've saw it. it just work on Windows.