# com4j 80040111 CoCreateInstance failed : ClassFactory cannot supply requested class

Tags: java, com4j

I want to write CD/DVD Burning Program in Java. After searching I found this Solution given over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8556661/2914428). I followed it but when I run this program I got error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com4j.ExecutionException: com4j.ComException: 80040111 CoCreateInstance failed : ClassFactory cannot supply requested class : .\com4j.cpp:153
    at com4j.ComThread.execute(ComThread.java:203)
    at com4j.Task.execute(Task.java:25)
    at com4j.COM4J.createInstance(COM4J.java:97)
    at com4j.COM4J.createInstance(COM4J.java:72)
    at com.ms.imapi2.ClassFactoryExt.createMsftDiscFormat2Data(ClassFactoryExt.java:16)
    at com.ms.main.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:19)
Caused by: com4j.ComException: 80040111 CoCreateInstance failed : ClassFactory cannot supply requested class : .\com4j.cpp:153
    at com4j.Native.createInstance(Native Method)
    at com4j.COM4J$CreateInstanceTask.call(COM4J.java:117)
    at com4j.COM4J$CreateInstanceTask.call(COM4J.java:104)
    at com4j.Task.invoke(Task.java:51)
    at com4j.ComThread.run0(ComThread.java:153)
    at com4j.ComThread.run(ComThread.java:134)
```

**Note**
I am running this program on 64bit Windows 7 with 64bit JVM.

**What I tried to solve :**

1) I registered `com4j.dll` using regsvr32

2) Added `com4j.dll` as Native libraries of `com4j.jar`

Is there problem in Code or Something else I have to do to make this run.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register com4j.dll in system. Instead this you should register your 3d-part dll.

Also make sure that you have java-classes for working with COM dll. They can be generate by using **tlbimp.jar** from Com4J folder.

```
java -jar tlbimp.jar -o "..." -p "..." absolute_path_for_dll
```

where

- **-o** - destination directory, where generated files will be located.
- **-p** - java package.

Example of using:

```
java -jar tlbimp.jar -o C:/projects/com4j/generated -p com.example C:/projects/dll/3d-part.dll
```

Check [tutorial](https://com4j.java.net/tutorial.html) for more information.

Comment: I did the same with IMAPI2.dll and IMAPIFS.dll, but still it throws exception.